# How to prevent PHP str_replace replace text in html tags?

Tags: php

I am developing a website where user can upload their texts. For managerial purpose, I want to 
change all the text "apple" to `<a href="https://apple.com">apple<a>` dynamically by php.

I am using `str_replace('apple','<a href="..">apple</a>')` Now

However, the word "apple" might already been linked to an external source by users. In this case,  will mess up the original link.

Say the page has the following :

```
<a href="...">apple</a>
```

my code will change it to

```
<a href="..."><a href="...">apple</a></a>
```

Is there any way I can identify if a certain "apple" was in an a tag or other html tags already?

Thank you

Comment: just apple? or other words?

Comment: I just need one keyword, "apple", for now.

Comment: you can look at the potential boundaries for the word

Answer (score 3):

Use `DOMDocument` to turn the HTML into a DOM you can work with. Then, iterate over all text nodes, making the replacements.

Comment: Are they uploading their links?  Also, str_replace in your example is not correctly setup - it should be $str = str_replace($search,$replace,$str) for example - is that just a typo?

Comment: @JasonMichael Yes, they are uploading links. And it's a typo.

Comment: better than parsing with regex and having this question posted again http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 0):

Would all occurrences of "Apple" be in regular sentences (i.e. preceded or followed by spaces or newlines)? If so, you could try something like this:

```
str_replace(' apple', ' <a href="..">apple</a>, $string);
```

If that wont do what you need, do a catch-all str_replace and then use preg_match with regex to get clean up any nested links. Something along the lines of this which would preserve the original link (though I don't recommend using regex to parse HTML).

```
preg_match('/\<a href="(.*)"\>\<a href="(.*)"\>(.*)\</a\>\</a\>', '<a href="\\1">\\3</a>', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use an `if` statement to look for the `<a href="..">`, `else` do your replacement?